# How can I prevent a disabled ToolStripMenuItem from showing a border on mouse over?

Tags: c#, winforms, border, toolstripmenu

Yes, exactly same as the title, in my project some of toolstripmenuitems were disabled. But when i bring the cursor over the menu item, a blue border is appearing like this:
[image]
But i don't want this. I want it like this:
[image]
 Could you help me, how do i prevent this blue border?

Comment: Thank you for correcting the title. I wrote very long to fully explain my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should create a custom `ToolStripRenderer`, take a look at this - [How to: Set the ToolStrip Renderer for an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229634.aspx)

1. You have to create a custom renderer like this:

   ```
   class CutomToolStripMenuRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
   {
       protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.Item.Enabled)
           base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
       }

       protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.Item.Enabled)
           base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And then set this renderer to your menu strip:

   ```
   menuStrip1.Renderer = new CustomToolStripRenderer();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I get a little more control of my "Disabled" menuItems by Switching between **ToolStripMenuItem** and a copy of the item as a **ToolStripLabel**.
Then instead of setting Enabled = false, I just toggle the visibility between the two.
This way I can have custom forecolors for the "Disabled" menuItem (Label).

```
    bool m_isStartSvcEnabled = true;


    void ToggleServiceEnabled()
    {
        m_isStartSvcEnabled = !m_isStartSvcEnabled;

        mnuStartSvc.Visible = m_isStartSvcEnabled;
        lblStartSvc.Visible = !m_isStartSvcEnabled;

        mnuStopSvc.Visible = !m_isStartSvcEnabled;
        lblStopSvc.Visible = m_isStartSvcEnabled;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

(White menu forecolor, and and lighter gray forecolor for the label I defined in the creation of the items.)