# How to avoid the contextMenu hightlight when enable is set to false in WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I'm using a ContextMentStrip in an application. I have set the enabeld property as false for a item. When I hover it, the item is highlighted as in the image.

[image]

I need to avoid the highlight when the enabled is set to false. Is there any way to avoid the items highlighted when the enabled property is set to false? If yes, please suggest me a way.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13365616/815938) helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent a disabled ToolStripMenuItem from showing a border on mouse over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364923/how-can-i-prevent-a-disabled-toolstripmenuitem-from-showing-a-border-on-mouse-ov)